# How create DB from other DB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have a DB.sqlite file on iOS8 phone.This file has 5 sqlite tables.
I read and write to this tables with my objective-c application.

What is the best way to create a smaller DB.sqlite file from the Global DB.sqlite file?

For example the new DB.sqlite tables contains the last 5 hours

Comment: used NSFileManager for copy complete DB.sqlite file to destinationPath and change the name.

Comment: But how create a small copy?

Comment: what do you mean by small copy?

Comment: NSFileManager copy complete DB file.

Comment: A global DB has 3 tables that contains data of 24 Hours,
i want every 5 hour create a copy of a global DB that all tables contain the data of last 5 hours(a small copy of DB)

Comment: you can create a copy of global DB called small DB and delete unused data small DB.